# How to get formset id/name

Tags: django, django-forms

I use formset in my template:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

formset_builder = inlineformset_factory(MyEntity, MyEntity.relation.through)
formset = formset_builder()
```

In my template, for an formset i can see:

```
<label for="id_theformsetid_set-0-mywidgetname">MyRelationAttribute</label>
```

How to get (in view, templates, ...) this "**theformsetid**" ? (*I would like use it to refactoring javascript during formset manipulation*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside view:

```
formset.fk.related.get_accessor_name()
```

Inside template:

```
formset.fk.related.get_accessor_name
```